# Nginx Rewrite Does not Work Correctly

Tags: nginx

I want to apply rewrite /author/xxx to /index.php?author_name=xxx

```
rewrite ^/author/(.*)/$ /index.php?author_name=$1;
```

When I apply code, browser url looks like that :

```
http://www.site-name.com/?author_name=xxx
```

I want url will look like :

http://www.site-name.com/author/xxx but it will rewrite index.php?author_name=xxx

Any idea to fix it?

My Nginx conf file is below :

```
server {
        server_name site-name.com;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://www.site-name.com$1 permanent;
        listen   8080;
        }
server {
        listen   8080;
        access_log off;
        # access_log   /home/www.site-name.com/logs/access_log;
        error_log on;
        # error_log /home/www.site-name.com/logs/error.log; 
        #add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        #add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://www.site-name.xyz";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        root /home/www.site-name.com/public_html;
        include /etc/nginx/conf/ddos2.conf;
        # include /etc/nginx/conf/cors.conf;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name www.site-name.com;



location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

}


rewrite ^/author/(.*)/$ /index.php?author_name=$1;




        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 250;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 250;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 250;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/www.site-name.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

include /etc/nginx/conf/drop.conf;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `rewrite` looks OK: From extern you can use `/author/...` and internally it will use `index.php?...`.

I suppose you also want to redirect `index.php?...` to the nice path:

```
rewrite ^/author/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?author_name=$1 break;
rewrite ^/index.php$ https://www.example.com/author/$arg_author_name/ redirect;
root /var/www/html/;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_pass php;
include fastcgi_params;
```

Comment: I applied it but all other pages redirect to http://www.example.com/author/

Comment: Then please write what you have for other sites besides author. I can't guess your whole setting. My first solution would be to organize the redirects with if or with a map, I'm waiting. ;)

Comment: Hello. I have only this site. It is a wordpress site. I have edited my question and added my domain nginx conf file.

Comment: Just put `if ($arg_author_name != "") { ... }` around my second line. Or better google for `wordpress nginx permalinks`.